# Иероглифы в строке состояния

Tags: c, winapi

Я создал такой `status bar`:

```
HWND stbar = CreateWindowExW(0, STATUSCLASSNAME, L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SBARS_SIZEGRIP,
                            0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, 0, hInst, NULL);
int parts[2] = { LOWORD(lParam)/ 2, LOWORD(lParam) };
SendMessage(stbar, SB_SETPARTS, 2, (LPARAM)parts);
SendMessage(stbar, SB_SETTEXT,  0, (LONG)"Text");
SendMessage(stbar, SB_SETTEXT,  1, (LONG)"123");
```

Но вместо нужного текста в ячейках строки состояния выводятся иероглифы.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А где тут `c++`?

Comment: @alexolut, код на нём ;)

Comment: @alexolut в своём коде я использую `std::string`; тут для упрощения `"Text"` и `"123"`, если вы об этом

Comment: @Qwertiy можно бы ещё и `c++17` тогда добавить с такими заявлениями :) А тут даже приведения в си-стиле.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Судя по `L""` ваша программа использует юникод. А в lparam вы передаете указатель на ASCII-строки. Попробуйте и в SendMessage использовать `(LONG)L"Text"`.

Comment: Точно, всё заработало, спасибо

Comment: @koss да пожалуйста! Только с std::string так, наверное, не прокатит. Придется std::wstring юзать.